# Select only year from MySql

Tags: mysql, date

I need to select only the year from the record date.

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT('release','%Y') AS release_year FROM books
```

but doesnt work. The result in phpmyadmin is NULL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT *, YEAR(`release`) AS release_year FROM books
```

I think `release` is a MySQL keyword. Try to wrap it around ``

Comment: Well, what is the data type of `release`?

Comment: Yes, the problem was 'release' instead `release`. Thanks

Comment: +1 you answered first, I added my answer only to include the link to the MySQL Reserved Words documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put `release` in quotes.  You're trying to extract the year from a literal string `'release'`, not the value in the column ``release``.

And as @invisal states, RELEASE is a [reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html), so you have to delimit it with back-ticks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem :

DATE_FORMAT(**'release'**,'%Y')

in Mysql that is a string.

Fix :

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(`release`,'%Y') AS release_year FROM books;
```