# Display all item which is created in 2013

Tags: mysql

I have a `table Policy`, and I want to display all policy which is created in `2013`.

```
select DAT_IZD from AUTO.KPOL   WHERE DAT_IZD='2013'
```

But the problem is that this format of date can not be represent like this.
Any idea how to figure out this ?

Comment: Assuming `DAT_IZD=` is a DATE or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP data type then `YEAR(DAT_IZD)='2013'` should work

Comment: What does the content of `DAT_IZD` look like? What is the data type of the column? If it's a `datetime` type, then then [YEAR()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function would probably help you, e.g. `WHERE YEAR(DAT_IZD) = '2013'`. P.S. Did you do any research into this? I'm fairly sure if you had googled "mysql match year" or similar you would have got the answer immediately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select only year from MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841760/select-only-year-from-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract year value (something like WHERE YEAR(DAT_IZD) = 2013) from date before you compare.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT DAT_IZD FROM AUTO.KPOL  WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DAT_IZD)= '2013' ;
```

or

```
SELECT DAT_IZD FROM AUTO.KPOL  WHERE YEAR(DAT_IZD)= '2013' ;
```

I hope this will help you